# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED when calling Azure library in docker container and in VS code running locally

Tags: python, docker, azure

I am reading a client certificate from Azure key vault in Python. Code in being run in VS code in windows.

I have following code

```
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
certificate_client = CertificateClient("url of keyvault", credential)
certificate = certificate_client.get_certificate("certificatename")
```

I am getting following error

> ServiceRequestError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate
> in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1002)

Then I installed "python-certifi-win32" package and error got fixed.
Then I created a docker container and I have this list of packages in the requirement.txt file

```
azure-functions
python-certifi-win32
azure.identity
azure.keyvault.certificates
azure.keyvault.secrets
requests_pkcs12
```

but then I got this error

> ---> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcException: Result: Failure
> Exception: ServiceRequestError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1007)
> Stack:   File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.10/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py",

my docker file has following content

```
# To enable ssh & remote debugging on app service change the base image to the one below
# FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.11-appservice
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.10-appservice
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true
COPY requirements.txt /

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted- 
host=files.pythonhosted.org --no-cache-dir -r /requirements.txt

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot
```

How can I fix this error please?